# Selenium Webdriver switch to another window and parse data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeName

[image: Click on BANKATLANTIC]

Click on BANKATLANTIC

[image]

How to extract the TransactionItemId? # under DocLink

How to extract the text from the 1st document?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driverurl = "https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeName"
RecordDateInput = "8/15/2017"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(driverurl)
driver.find_element_by_id("btnButton").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("Direct").click() # Grantor

Name = "ba"
driver.find_element_by_id("SearchOnName").send_keys(Name)

DocType = "RELEASE/REVOKE/SATISFY OR TERMINATE (RST)"
driver.find_element_by_id("DocTypesDisplay-input").clear()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("DocTypesDisplay-input").send_keys(DocType)

driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateFrom").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateFrom").send_keys(RecordDateInput)
driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateTo").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("RecordDateTo").send_keys(RecordDateInput)

driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearch"))
driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearch").click()
sleep(7)

driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rowNumClass")[0].click()
sleep(3)

#######################################################
# solution:

driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
sleep(3)

html = driver.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") 

TransactionItemId = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "listDocDetails" })[-1].find("a")['onclick'].split("'")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to get the element that contains $600,000 is to get the element that contains the "Consideration:" label and then find the following `DIV` that contains the dollar amount. The only way to find an element by contained text is to use an XPath. The one below works.

```
//div[@class='detailLabel'][contains(.,'Consideration:')]/following-sibling::div
```

Comment: thanks, but I've used soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "listDocDetails" })[-2].get_text().strip()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
sleep(3)

html = driver.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") 

TransactionItemId = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "listDocDetails" })[-1].find("a")['onclick'].split("'")[1]
```